# XCode 6.3 MKPointAnnotation setCoordinate missing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mkpointannotation

I just updated XCode to 6.3 and now I am receiving the below error:
MKPointAnnotation does not have a member named 'setCoordinate'.

Not sure where it went, or if we are supposed to use some other MK method.  Any help is appreciated.

```
func refreshlocation(lat:String, lon:String, withOffset:Bool = false){


        // 1 Convert the string values to something that can be used.
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: (lat as NSString).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees,
            longitude: (lon as NSString).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
        )

        // 2 setup some initial variables.
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(
            (self.locationLatitudeDelta as NSString).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees,
            (self.locationLongitudeDelta as NSString).doubleValue as CLLocationDegrees
        )

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        //3 decorate the point and add the point to the map.
        var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.setCoordinate(location) //Error on this line

    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As stated in the [iOS 8.3 API Diffs in the MapKit module](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS83APIDiffs/modules/MapKit.html), the `setCoordinate` method was removed:

> *Removed* MKAnnotation.setCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D)

Fortunately, you must now use the simpler assignment syntax (which was already available in previous versions of Swift and the same could be done in Objective-C):

```
annotation.coordinate = location
```

Comment: Thanks, I will review that doc.

Comment: coordinate is a read only property so after initially setting it you can't change it directly.

Comment: Since it's read-only what should you do in order to change `coordinate`?

Comment: Based on Apple docs, `coordinate` is read/write for Swift. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpointannotation/1452620-coordinate