# MKUserLocation coordinate is now read-only in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, mkuserlocation

I had the pulsating dot of the `MKUserLocation` in my App. 
Now with the new `Xcode 6.3` the `MapKit` changed so the following code is not working anymore.

```
var anno = MKUserLocation()
anno.coordinate = locationNew
```

as well the `setCoordinate()` method is removed from the `MapKit`.

**Has someone an idea how to get the pulsating dot to a custom location in MapView?**

Comment: there is no coordinate property in MKUserLocation class. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008424-CH1-SW2

Comment: Why so you want to set the user location? The location of the user can't be updated by yourself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548143/xcode-6-3-mkpointannotation-setcoordinate-missing.  However, you still cannot set the coordinate on an MKUserLocation because it is the default read-only like the MKAnnotation protocol says.  Other classes such as MKPointAnnotation override coordinate as read-write.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: MKUserLocation _does_ have a coordinate property (an annotation by definition _must_ have a coordinate property).  This isn't obvious from that doc link but note that it conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol in which coordinate is a required property.

Comment: In an earlier release it was possible to instanciate an MKUserLocation and manipulate the coordinates to generate a pulsating dot on a MapView at a custom location. Is there another workaround for this?